# What traffic does Block(default) option block in Windows Firewall

Tags: networking, windows-10, firewall, windows-defender

I wanted to block all traffic, but from the device I remotely access the windows machine.

I opened Advanced settings in Windows Defender and after a lot of trial and error with new rules, realised that I that there are additional settings located somewhere else as shown in the picture:

[image]

I realised that my remote desktop connection didn't end when I turned on `"Block(default)"` setting. But it does break if you tick `"Block All Connections"` option.

I wonder, what traffic gets through firewall if `"Block(default)"` is enabled? Clearly it lets port 3389 alive.

Answer (score 0):

Everything that's not matched by a rule. For RDP and such you usually have Firewall rules that are supplied by Microsoft unless you decide to disable them. Turning on RDP usually results in a message that tells you that those rules will be enabled.